# C Reading numbers from file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file

hey so i m trying to read numbers from text file and put them into an array but ive been getting weird numbers when i try to print them. text file looks like:

```
45
77
8
...
```

i guess theres something wrong with the loop i m using but i cant seem to find out what.
thanks for your help!

code:

```
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 20

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *myFile;
    int myArray[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
    //char filename[32];
    //printf("enter filename\n");
    //scanf("%s", filename);

    myFile = fopen("asdf.txt", "r");
    if (!myFile) {
        printf("cant open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int status;
    int i = 0;
    while ((status = fscanf(myFile, "%2d", &myArray[i])) == 1 && i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE - 1) {
        ++i;
    }
    fclose(myFile);


    int a;
    for (a = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", myArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (a = 0; a < i; ++a) {
        printf("%d ", myArray[a]);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your print loop:

```
for (a = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
```

There is no guarantee you are reading `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` values. Also, if you ar using `'a'` as your loop iterator, then you need to use `'a'`. Your loop should be:

```
for (a = 0; a < i; ++a)
    printf("%d ", myArray[a]);
```

You also do not need a field-width in your *format-specifier*, `fscanf(myFile, " %d", &myArray[i]))` will do.

Comment: yeah :D i was using "i" before and forgot to change all of them to a :D thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while ((status = fscanf(myFile, "%d\n", &myArray[i])) == 1 && i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE - 1) {
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

True... I have not seen print loop code.. Sorry.
Problem is in print loop not fscan, please ignore my answer

Comment: You can edit your answer to change it as required. Do not submit another answer.

Comment: You should delete this answer.